# ArrayAdapter text and image

Tags: android, image, adapter

In my activity I implement a list which contains the names of some files.
Every list's item refers to a layout in which I'd like to show the name of the images and a thumbnail of the image referenced. Ican show the the name using an ArrayAdapter but i don't know hot to insert the image thumbnail.
All the image referenced stay in sd_card and i have the path of they.
Here is the single row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_nav_background_default" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titoloTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the layout of the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/creaButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Crea una nuova realtà aumentata" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Ar già create"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the activity code inherent adapter.

```
    ArrayAdapter<?> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.titoloTv,targetName);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  
           @Override  
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, final View componente, int pos, long id){

...................            
           } 

    });
```

I'm trying using this but doesn't work properly.

```
    String tempTarget;
    List<Map<String,Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

   for(int i = 0; i<ARelements.size();i++){
        Element ar = arIterator.next();

        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>(2);
        tempTarget = ar.getAttributeValue("TARGET");
        thumbnailBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempTarget), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
        map.put("thumbnail", thumbnailBitmap);
        map.put("titolo", tempTarget);
        data.add(map);
    }
   arIterator= null;

   SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,data,R.layout.row,new String[] {"thumbnail","titolo"},new int[] {R.id.imageView, R.id.titoloTv});


    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

Comment: search for "custom array adapter".

Comment: Can you provide the missing part where you get/show the text/name of the image... this should be in the `getView()` method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to implement a custom array adapter and specify that imageview and textview layout/id(s) in the adapter.

Something like:

```
  public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {


    Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, //resourceId=your layout
            List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

Refer Extending other Adapters too, for ListView(s) and their custom implementation:
Eg.
http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

Comment: Is `RowItem` another class you created separately? What does it contain, the code for manipulating the row items? Just not sure how it all fits together.

Comment: Row item would be another model related to the adapter n list item

Answer (score 6):

You don't necessarily need a custom ArrayAdapter, a SimpleAdapter will do the trick for a thumbnail/text combo. You can store the path to the thumbnail and the text you want in a HashMap array, and then apply it using a SimpleAdapter. For example, if you had 5 thumbnails + text and arrays of each:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Map<String, Object> datum = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
            datum.put("thumbnail", thumbnail[i]);
            datum.put("name", text[i]);
            data.add(datum);
        }
YourListViewId.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.yoursinglerowlayout, new String[] {"thumbnail","name"}, new int[] {R.id.imageView, R.id.titoloTv}));
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this trik but doesn't work.I see only empty records bordered from a line.I post my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

First: You will have to change your ArrayAdapter to BaseAdapter because BaseAdapter gives you more flexibility with the views. Try to use this code and see how it works:

Here's how I am getting images from sd card and populating it in a listview

```
public class GetSdCardContent extends Activity {

    public static Cursor cursor;
    private int columnIndex;
    private File file;
    private String SD_CARD_ROOT;
    ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    File[] listFile;
    ImageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sdcard_layout);
        

        getSdcardImages();
        
        
        ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sdlistView1);
        adapter = new ImageAdapter();
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    public void getSdcardImages() {
        File file = new File(
                android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(),
                "Pictures");

        
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listFile = file.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                Log.i("FILES:"+"---", f.toString());

            }
        }
    }
```

This is the adapter I am using. It's a base adapter and I am getting only images for now. You can also add your TextView if you want to.

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return f.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_items,
                        null);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.customimageView1);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));
            try {
                
                holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(myBitmap, 300, 300));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

[This method](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/) is for bitmap, if you want to resize your image and stuff:

```
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;

    }
}
```

Last part: Two layouts.

One: layout for items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/customimageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bluebutton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Second: Main Layout. (ListView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sdlistView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView> 


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the fact is that I can't reference my image from an id because I need to use images from the sd card.

Comment: So after you get the images from SD card, I guess you are querying for the image, so after you get the query result, store the result in the array list and then you can add one more arraylist in the base adapter adapter and make that changes to ur MainActivity.

Comment: If you can also add other imp code, it will be more easy to track the thing that you want to accomplish.

Comment: I try to use your code and tomorrow I will let you know if works.

Comment: just one question. Which method should i use to set my image from a path?

Comment: You are using a Cursor to get the images right ? You just have to query the DB to get the images. Now depending on what images you want to pull, the paths will be different. I can post full answer after a while.

Comment: no i'm not using a Cursor. The images are stored in the sd card and i can reference their using the file path mnt/sd_card/....../images.jpg

Comment: @TWONEKSONE I have changed the answer. Check it and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it using this class

```
public class ExtendedSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{
List<HashMap<String, Object>> map;
String[] from;
int layout;
int[] to;
Context context;
LayoutInflater mInflater;
public ExtendedSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, Object>> data,
        int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    layout = resource;
    map = data;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
return this.createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, layout);
}

private View createViewFromResource(int position, View convertView,
    ViewGroup parent, int resource) {
View v;
if (convertView == null) {
    v = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
} else {
    v = convertView;
}

this.bindView(position, v);

return v;
}


private void bindView(int position, View view) {
final Map dataSet = map.get(position);
if (dataSet == null) {
    return;
}

final ViewBinder binder = super.getViewBinder();
final int count = to.length;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
    if (v != null) {
        final Object data = dataSet.get(from[i]);
        String text = data == null ? "" : data.toString();
        if (text == null) {
            text = "";
        }

        boolean bound = false;
        if (binder != null) {
            bound = binder.setViewValue(v, data, text);
        }

        if (!bound) {
            if (v instanceof Checkable) {
                if (data instanceof Boolean) {
                    ((Checkable) v).setChecked((Boolean) data);
                } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                    // Note: keep the instanceof TextView check at the bottom of these
                    // ifs since a lot of views are TextViews (e.g. CheckBoxes).
                    setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() +
                            " should be bound to a Boolean, not a " +
                            (data == null ? "<unknown type>" : data.getClass()));
                }
            } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                // Note: keep the instanceof TextView check at the bottom of these
                // ifs since a lot of views are TextViews (e.g. CheckBoxes).
                setViewText((TextView) v, text);
            } else if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                if (data instanceof Integer) {
                    setViewImage((ImageView) v, (Integer)     data);                            
                } else if (data instanceof Bitmap){
                    setViewImage((ImageView) v, (Bitmap)data);
                } else {
                    setViewImage((ImageView) v, text);
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a " +
                        " view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter");
            }
        }
    }
}
}



private void setViewImage(ImageView v, Bitmap bmp){
v.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}



}
```