# How to dynamically draw image in ListView rows in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview for shopping List, each row basically displays items. In the row layout I have simple imageview icon and text for the item and number of items. I would like to draw an icon (like a bullet) for each row, but the bullet size depends on how many items for each row (I am thinking of drawing a circle and make size of radius as percentage of number of items).

```
class Item
class ListActivity extends Activity
class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>
```

Where/how Can I draw the image and where do I set it? I believe it envolves creating a canvas in ListAdapter?

Comment: why not use `ImageView` for each row?

Comment: I am, but how do I draw to it, where do I place the code, and what do I have to override - newbie to Android

Comment: Maybe you can follow this post [ArrayAdapter text and image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833181/arrayadapter-text-and-image)

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks