# How to update the image of each ImageView of a ListView in Android with new image for each one

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-imageview

I am fetching texts first and adding them to the ListView (This part is working).
Then for each item in the ListView I am fetching an image and need to add this image to the ImageView of each item which is already defined in the layout.
I am able to get all the images but don't know how to update the ListView with the same.

```
//AsyncTask For texts.
private class pgData extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
        publishProgress("Starting");
        String result=null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxx.xxx/xxx.php");
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpEntity httpentity =null;
        JSONArray t=null;
        try{
            response= httpclient.execute(httppost);
            httpentity=response.getEntity();
            result= EntityUtils.toString(httpentity);
            t=new JSONArray(result);
        }catch (Exception e){
            publishProgress(e.toString());
            this.cancel(true);
        }
        return  t;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... i) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), i[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
            String x[];
            l = result.length();
            pg_data = new pg[l];
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = result.getJSONObject(i);
                    x[0] = jsonObject.getString("xxx");
                    x[1]=jsonObject.getString("xxx");
                    x[2] = jsonObject.getString("xxxx");
                    x[3] = jsonObject.getString("rentMonthly");
                    pg_data[i] = new pg(
                            x[0],
                            x[1],
                            x[2],
                            x[3]
                    );
                    jdata.add(xxx_data[i]);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            adapter = new pgAdapter(second.this,
                    R.layout.pg,
                    xxx_data);
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            new xxImage().execute(); //exexuting async task for fetching images.
    }
}

//Async Task for fetching images
private class xxImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
        publishProgress("Getting Images");
        String result=null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxx.xx/xx.php");
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpEntity httpentity =null;
        JSONArray t=null;
        try{
            response= httpclient.execute(httppost);
            httpentity=response.getEntity();
            result= EntityUtils.toString(httpentity);
            t=new JSONArray(result);
        }catch (Exception e){
            publishProgress(e.toString());
            this.cancel(true);
        }
        return  t;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... i) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), i[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
            String image1;
            l = result.length();
            xx_image = new xxImage[l];
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = result.getJSONObject(i);
                    image1 = "\n" + jsonObject.getString("image1") + "\n";
                    xx_image[i] = new xxImage(
                            image1
                    );
                    jimage.add(xx_image[i]);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            //I got all the Images in 'jimage'. Now how to update the ListView from here?
        }
    }
```

Comment: really, Honestly dont use `AsyncTask` use `Callback Pattern` with `Runnable` and since you wanna update `UI Thread` use `Holder` Class  to add images to the ‍‍`UI`

Comment: You should definitely consider using an image loading library, such as, Picasso. It really simplifies your work for losing images and handles unseen errors your code will have. In regards to displaying the image in an adapter, it depends on what View you are using to display them, but follow this tutorial for advice: http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: I read it everywhere that one just have to add the new data to the adapter and notify it but I am not able to implement it. Can you help me out please?

Comment: @chRyNaN I am getting all the images easily but not able to update them in the ListView. Suppose there are 3 items then I will be getting 3 images and I want to update the respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second AsyncTask do the following in the loop:

1. parse your image after getting it in image1.
2. get the item at i from the adapter.
3. from that item find the view with its id.
4. set the image on it.

Done. Try, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom ArrayAdapter for doing this. In you first asyncTask you set the adapter using the text data that you have but the adapter that you are using is of the form

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
```

In your case T is String (as far as I can see). But you want this T to be a custom object which also includes an image. You can do this by building your own custom adapter. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833181/arrayadapter-text-and-image) answer.

Or another way is that your T object should be something like this.

```
CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject(text, image).
```

Try creating a list of these objects which you will then pass to the adapter instead of passing just the text array. But for this you will have to wait till all the images are loaded.

A better idea is to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). And implement a custom Adapter. Your current approach is very flawed.

Comment: my images are in database not web server that's why I can't use Picasso. Can you write the left part of the second async task because I am really not able to do this.