# How to populate a list view item with xml layout in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am working on an Android project and I want to populate a listview item with an XML layout. The layout consists of an image text box and a TextView.

How can I do this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: search google for "Custom adapter with listview in android example"..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArrayAdapter text and image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833181/arrayadapter-text-and-image)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create model for the objects then create a custom ArrayAdapter of type model as shown below

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyModel> {

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyModel> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.Your_xml_layout, viewGroup, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Your_TextView_id);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Your_ImageView_id);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    MyModel myModel = getItem(position);

    viewHolder.textView.setText(myModel.getter_for_textView);    
    viewHolder.imageView // Load your image to the imageView

   return view;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
}

}
```

In your main activity, get the reference to the listView, create an object of your adapter and set the adapter on the listview.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way,you need to create custom adapter

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

listitem

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />


</LinearLayout >
```

Adapter

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Activity context;
private final String[] web;
private final Integer[] imageId;
public CustomList(Activity context,
String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
this.context = context;
this.web = web;
this.imageId = imageId;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
return rowView;
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    String[] web = {
        "Google Plus",
            "Twitter",
            "Windows",
            "Bing",
            "Itunes",
            "Wordpress",
            "Drupal"
    } ;
    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4,
            R.drawable.image5,
            R.drawable.image6,
            R.drawable.image7

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomList adapter = new
                CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

    }

}
```